# In Bitbucket Server is it possible to restrict pull requests to require them to be up-to-date with the target branch?

Tags: git, bitbucket

We are using Bitbucket server using the [git-flow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) branching model.

I have already used branch restrictions to disallow push to master/develop except via pull requests.

I now want to add a further restriction that a merge in the PR cannot be performed unless it is up-to-date with the develop branch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set merge strategies for pull requests. Fast-forward only is the one you want to enable for the outcome you describe.

https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/pull-request-merge-strategies-844499235.html

Comment: Thanks, I'll try give this a shot. Do you know if ff-only merge strategy creates a merge commit still?

Comment: It does not, I'm afraid. I thought there was an open suggestion for this on https://jira.atlassian.com/projects/BSERV/issues/BSERV-9575?filter=allopenissues , but I couldn't find anything. Feel free to create one!

Answer (score -1):

Look into implementing repository hooks.

https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/server/docs/latest/how-tos/repository-hooks.html